# Plot won't show data expressed as large fractions

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot a probability function that has large fractions between 0 and 1, but `Plot` returns an empty graph.

The strange thing is that when I adjust the sampling using the output slider or adjust the line thickness, I can briefly see the graph before it goes away once I let go.

I'm currently on version 11.0.

Here's my code:

```
func[x_] := 365!/((365 - x)! 365^x)
Plot[func[x], {x, 0, 100}]
```

I've also tried defining `func[x_]` as `N[...]` (calculating the numerical value), but that makes no difference.

Comment: I don't know how to fix this, but if all you care about is how the function looks like you can get around the problem by explicitly evaluating it for a list of values: `ListLinePlot[Table[{x, func[x]}, {x, 100}]]`

Comment: @yohbs That's okay for now, but I noticed this problem with several other functions involving really large or tiny numbers (can't recall them right now). I'm wondering if this is a bug or not.

Comment: @jLee I get a plot using your code on MMA 11.1.0 .

Comment: @jLee I get a plot using $Version "11.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 16, 2017)"

Answer (score 1):

For functions that might not work directly even on 64-bit machines, you might consider the old-fashioned way using logs:

```
func[x_] := Exp[LogGamma[365 + 1] - LogGamma[365 - x + 1] - x Log[365]]
Plot[func[x], {x, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Function plot]

Answer (score 0):

**Comment**

I am facing the same issue of seeing an empty plot.

*"11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)"*

Another alternative is to use `DiscretePlot`,

```
func[x_] := 365!/((365 - x)!* 365^x);

DiscretePlot[func[x], {x, 0, 100}, Filling -> None, Joined -> True]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Perhaps your issue is that you are on a 32-bit OS. On a Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) I have no problem.

Comment: @BobHanlon Maybe that is the case.

Comment: @BobHanlon that may be the case since I ran it on my 64 bit Mac OS X machine and it worked, but not my 32 bit Windows machine

Answer (score 0):

Use `FactorialPower[]` instead to sidestep any possible overflow issues:

```
Plot[FactorialPower[365, x] 365^-x, {x, 0, 100}]
```

[image: function plot]